# MySQL doesn't use index when range is too large

Tags: mysql, indexing, range

I'm working with 2 queries :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ecpm AS cpm, date_added, cpid, sales
FROM table1
WHERE date_added >=20130501000000
AND date_added <20140531235959
```

And

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ecpm AS cpm, date_added, cpid, sales
FROM table1
WHERE date_added >=20140501000000 
AND date_added <20140531235959
```

The first query is working with 1079470 rows and 14942 for the second.

My problem : the first query doesn't use the INDEX :

```
1   SIMPLE  table1  ALL PRIMARY,date_added  NULL    NULL    NULL    1079470 Using where
```

Whereas the second does :

```
1   SIMPLE  table1  range   PRIMARY,date_added  date_added  8   NULL    14942   Using where
```

What parameter should I work with to enable to use of the INDEX wether my range is large or not ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that MySQL has determined that it is more efficient to avoid the index for the larger range because it will end up scanning the entire table anyway (based on the optimizer prune settings).

I would recommend reading up on MySQL Query Optimizations: [Controlling the Query Optimizer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/controlling-optimizer.html).  More specifically take a look at the [optimizer prune levels](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_optimizer_prune_level).

Here is more info on the `EXPLAIN` query: [Optimizing queries with EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: Even when modifying optimizer settings, it's not changing behaviour:

    mysql> SET optimizer_switch='index_merge=off,index_merge_union=off,index_merge_sort_union=off';